# Virtual Desktop Manager that mantain taskbar order in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-desktop, desktop-management

someone knows a VDM that keeps taskbar order when switching between desktops? I have tested several applications but none seems to be even interested in the problem. Is incredible anoying when I put the aplications in the order that I wan't and when I make the transitions that order is lost.
One alternative is pin all the open applications but that has the consequence that I'm going to have useless taskbar items in the rest of desktops. For me is important the order because I use extensively the Windows+Number to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a lot of time Dexpot has released in the 1.5.13 build the feature that i want. Is called Dynamic Windows Reordering and use the works of Rammichael.